# Errors with ViewState Cache and Update Panel

Tags: updatepanel, cache, viewstate

We have an application page that stores some information in the view state, and uses UpdatePanels. We have a rare, intermittent bug that occurs in SharePoint 2013 only whereby sometimes, after a button click (that should trigger a partial refresh via an UpdatePanel), the page goes back to it's blank state.

I finally caught this with an interesting ULS log:

```
Unexpected error occurred in method 'GetObject' , usage
'SPViewStateCache' - Exception
'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException:
ErrorCode<ERRCA0018>:SubStatus<ES0001>:The request timed out.
```

I was able to reproduce the bug once by stopping/starting the distributed cache service while working with the page (however, I couldn't do it consistently).

So, first of all, is this likely the culprit, and second, is it possible to disable the ViewStateCache for a particular page?

This is an admin page that only a few people would even have access to, and I don't think caching is helping anything at the best of times.

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the timeout with Powershell. Take a look at this blog post for the commands. http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/8657/fix-sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-timeouts.aspx

```
$LogonTokenCache = Get-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache
 $LogonTokenCache.RequestTimeout = 300 
Set-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache -DistributedCacheClientSettings $LogonTokenCache 


$ViewStateCache = Get-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedViewStateCache
 $ViewStateCache.RequestTimeout = 300 
Set-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedViewStateCache -DistributedCacheClientSettings $ViewStateCache
```

By running Get-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType CacheName you are able to see what the current request timeout is set to. By default, Microsoft sets the value of the RequestTimeout to 20 milliseconds. As a result, if the server is under any significant stress you will start seeing a lot of misses on calls to the cache.

```
PS C:\Users\user> $viewstatecache 
ChannelInitializationTimeout : 60000 
ConnectionBufferSize : 131072 
MaxBufferPoolSize : 268435456 
MaxBufferSize : 8388608 
MaxOutputDelay : 2 
ReceiveTimeout : 60000 
ChannelOpenTimeOut : 20 
RequestTimeout : 300 
MaxConnectionsToServer : 99
```